# React won't play Audio

Tags: reactjs, audio

In my React project I've got this `PresentationManager` class that I call a simple method on at the end of my index.js file, like so:

```
presentationManager.startPresentation();
```

And the method does only the following:

```
var scoreAudio = new Audio("path/to/myWav.wav");
scoreAudio.load();
scoreAudio.volume = 0.5;
scoreAudio.play();
```

When I run my code these lines are executed without any Exceptions but no audio plays.

If I take the exact same 4 lines, and put them inside an HTML page script tag and nothing else, it works perfectly, and plays my audio.

Any idea why?

Below is the complete code of my index.js file.

Paul

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import pData from './data/pData.js';
import tData from './data/tData.js';
import PresentationManager from './presentation/PresentationManager.js';

var presentationManager = new PresentationManager(tData, pData);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App presMgr={ presentationManager }/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

presentationManager.startPresentation();
```

Comment: Interestingly, I stumbled upon the fact that if I add an empty `audio` tag to my index.html body, it works!

Comment: But this doesn't really solve the problem, as I will need to play multiple audio files like this whose number and paths are not known at compile time.

Comment: Wow. It actually does work with multiple calls to create and play an Audio element. Just need one such tag in the HTML. Bizarre.

Comment: Please share your `scoreAudio` code inside of the component as well.

Comment: React has some issue with audio play... i think there is bug filed .

Comment: @elmeister, if you mean I should paste my scoreAudio code here, well, it's just the contents of the `startPresentation` function as I pasted it above, i.e.,

`startPresentation() {
 var scoreAudio = new Audio("path/to/myWav.wav");
 scoreAudio.load();
 scoreAudio.volume = 0.5;
 scoreAudio.play();
}`